# How can I fit multiple pages on to one A3 PDF page in Adobe InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, adobe-acrobat

[image]I want the document in the screenshot below to export as PDF on a single A3 paper format with crop marks.

So all 6 pages have to fit on a single page, A3 print size.

Right now I am only able to get it exported as 6 individual pages.

**How can I place my pages so that all 6 pages fit on to one A3 page in a PDF?**

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose? You could open it in Acrobat and print to pdf with the [Multiple pages per sheet option](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-multiple-pages-per-sheet.html) _( Can be found under the "Page sizing & handling > Multiple" tab in newer versions )_

Comment: That's the answer, @Joonas. You should make this an answer rather than a comment so it can be voted and accepted.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson, but that was your one and only wish. Are you sure you don't want to wish for my freedom...? Well alright... (ಥ‸ಥ) [Here you go](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30944/fitting-multiple-pages-on-1-pdf-page/30998#30998).

Comment: @Joonas, the purpose is to have a pdf ready to print. Can't it be done with InDesign instead?

Comment: Ok, so... the point of it is still a bit unclear to me.  Is there a specific reason why you aren't making it as a single A3 document to begin with?

Comment: @Joonas, thank  you for helping me out. The idea is to have a folding brochure, where each fold is page. The advantage of this is that every page can have a different layout and the order of pages can easily be changed. I have added an extra image that hopefully clarifies it.

Answer (score 3):

You can open up a multi-page pdf in Acrobat and print it out as a pdf with multiple pages in one sheet.

---

1. In Acrobat you go to Print <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>
2. Select pdf printer (probably something like: `Adobe PDF`) from your list of printers .
3. Next, depending on your version..

   - Older versions: Can be found under [`Page scaling multiple pages per sheet`](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-multiple-pages-per-sheet.html).
   - Newer versions: Can be found under `Page sizing & handling > Multiple`. <sup>The above link may be useful for newer versions as well.</sup>
4. Choose how many pages per sheet...
5. Then print away.

<sub>( It's very likely that you don't have pdf printer in your list,
   if you don't have Acrobat installed)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Alright, now that I know what needs to happen, I know what I would do.

This should be a fairly quick and effortless method, even for large grids and even if you have to do this more than once.

<sup>*However this explanation is going to be very long, because I want to make sure everyone can do it*</sup>

#### 1. Exporting pages as separate pdf files

1. Open Scripts panel in Indesign. `Window > Utilities > Scripts`
2. Right-click "User" script folder in the Scripts panel and choose "Reveal in finder"  <sup>( Or the windows equivalent, what ever that might be )</sup>
3. Download [PageExporterUtility5.0.1.jsx](http://indesignsecrets.com/page-exporter-utility-peu-5-script-updated-for-cs3.php) script.

   - Export it into that "User" scripts folder you just opened in step two.
   - After that it should  show up in the Indesign Scripts panels "User" folder. [image]
4. Make sure you have the document you want to export open and active.

   - Double click the script in the scripts panel.
   - The only thing you need to change in the script options is the `Output format`.
   - Then just click OK and choose a destination folder.

[image]

---

#### 2. Placing multiple images in a grid

1. Make a new document (In the OP's case that would be the A3 size document)

   - Make gutters 0, unless you really need to have gutters.
2. Choose all of the page pdf files you wish to place.

   - Either use "Place" <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> and use shift or control to select multiple files at the same time
   - OR just drag the files to your indesign document straight from the folder.
3. Start placing the images like you normally would...

   - Drag from the upper left corner to the lower right corner ( Don't let go yet! )
   - While still holding down the mouse button, tap the arrow keys to add rows and colums

     - Up arrow - Adds a row
     - Down arrow - Deletes a row
     - Right arrow - Adds a column
     - Left arrow - Deletes a row
   - If you desired to keep gutters in this document you will see a gutter between the grid sections. Doesn't matter either way, really.
   - After you have a desired grid, let go of your mouse button, and the images will be placed in the grid inside their own frames. [image]

---

#### 3. Joining the rows and columns

1. Right-click anywhere in the documents and choose `Fitting > Fit frame to content`.

   - [image]
2. Select the `Gap` tool.

   - Drag between a row and/or a column while holding <kbd>Cmd+</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> (mac) *or* <kbd>Ctrl+</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> (windows)
   - Drag until the rows and/or columns are joined [image]

Comment: The simpler answer is to Place multi-page pdf into stack and place it one by one into the document forming a grid manually.